# Lightbox thumbnail issue: header width becoming extended when viewing image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Having a weird issue that I'm not exactly sure how to fix.

I am using a jQuery lightbox gallery called "Fancy Gallery" for my portfolio images (found here: http://codecanyon.net/item/fancy-gallery-jquery-plugin/157532?ref=radykal&ref=radykal&clickthrough_id=643194202&redirect_back=true )

The issue I'm having is when the website is viewed on tablet or smart phone sizes.

When the user goes to the "Portfolio" section and clicks on one of the thumbsnails while the width of the page is say 500px, the header extends causing a shift in the site.

You can see this by looking at the following link: http://www.colorthegrayscale.com/CTG%20Developer/index

Any help with this weird glitch would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a horizontal scrollbar that is always visible (chrome 48.02xxx). 2. Using Chrome developer tools, deleting the `<svg>` node eliminates the horizontal scrollbar. My best guess would be checking if  `svg.min.js` is the blame. I hope this points you in the right direction.